# Drawing the Line between Coding Style and Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, coding-style

Formatting with Indentations, White spaces, and New Lines obviously fit into the *coding style* category.

```
if (a == b) {
    foo();
}

// vs

if (a == b)
{
    foo();
}
```

On the other hand, something that changes the run time of a program is no longer a matter of coding style, and becomes a matter of *algorithm*.

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    // Remove first element of the array.
    a.shift();
}

// vs

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    // Remove last element of the array.
    a.pop();
}
```

However, at what point does a matter of coding style turn into a matter of algorithm?

In other words, when comparing two possible methods to write the same program, when can we objectively determine whether the choice between the two methods is a *preference in coding style* or a *difference in algorithm*?

Is comparing to `true` a matter of coding style or algorithm?

```
if (a == true) {
    // a is true.
}

// vs

if (a) {
    // a is true.
}
```

Is returning `true` a matter of coding style or algorithm?

```
function isA(b) {
    return this.a == b;
}

// vs

function isA(b) {
    if (this.a == b) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

What about merging conditions into one `if` statement?

```
if (a > 0) {
    return foo();
}

if (b == 0) {
    return foo();
}

// vs

if (a > 0 || b == 0) {
    return foo();
}
```

Loop conditions?

```
// Loop 10 times.
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++);

// vs

// Loop 10 times.
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++);
```

Nested `if` statements?

```
function foobar() {
    if (a) {
        return foo();
    }

    if (b) {
        return bar();
    }

    return barfoo();
}

// vs

function foobar() {
    if (a) {
        return foo();
    } else {
        if (b) {
            return bar();
        } else {
            return barfoo();
        }
    }
}
```

These examples don't exactly change the run time of a program, yet isn't exactly just indentations, white spaces, or new line changes either. They are also typically not mentioned in coding style guides for most languages.

Given these examples above and other similar examples, **is the difference a matter *coding style* or *algorithm*? Or is there a completely different term for it?**

For example, if I am someone who uses `for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)`, do I simply have a different preference for coding style compared to someone who uses `for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++)`? Or is there something more to it besides *just* coding style? At what point is it no longer *just* coding style and start becoming part of the algorithm?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clean readable code vs fast hard to read code. When to cross the line?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/89620/clean-readable-code-vs-fast-hard-to-read-code-when-to-cross-the-line)

Comment: I think there is some difference between this question and `Clean readable code vs fast hard to read code. When to cross the line?`. In my question, the examples I've given are arguably equally clean, readable, and fast. However, I am asking that at what point do equally clean, readable, and fast code no longer become a preference of coding style and start becoming more than that. (if ever)

Comment: Besides coding style, there is also *idiomatic usage* of a language. This essentially means what is customary among users of a particular language (and sometimes even a sub-group of users).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer:

Are the two versions of code *capable of producing different outcomes when executed*? If so, they are probably different algorithms.

The kinds of outcomes we're concerned with:

- Results of the execution. For example, `shift` and `pop` modifies the array in different ways, so the content of the array is different. Any other code that has access to the array needs to be aware of how it was intended to be modified.
- Differences in qualities, or ["non-functional requirements"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement). For example, if the time taken by the operation "grows linearly (proportional) to the current size of the array", its performance is different from another which "grows quadratically to (proportional to the square of) the current size of the array", then it is likely that the two code implements two different algorithms.
- There are many other outcomes we might be concerned with, depending on the nature of the software projects.

---

Longer answer:

To be able to reason about whether some code changes will result in a change in the algorithm, one needs to:

- Reason logically. Article: [boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra).
- Understand the rules of the language very well.
- Have a simplified mental model of how the code would be executed, step-by-step, by a computer (or computer program / virtual machine).
- Understand possible ways in which the compiler or the execution program may diverge from your simplified mental model.

  - Code transformations that might be done by an optimizing compiler. Article: [optimizing compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler)
  - Effects of caching. Article: [cache (computing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing))
  - Race condition. Article: [race condition (software)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software)
  - Transient network failures